# Should I use taglib or HTML? What's the purpose of Struts taglib?

Tags: jsp, struts2

I'm dabbling into JSP after having experienced most of life as a PHP developer. I'm quite comfortable with Java as it is, so I've started to get to know Struts as my MVC framework of choice.

I'm having trouble understanding the reasons why I should use the Struts taglib instead of standard HTML?

```
<s:textfield id="username" />
```

or

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
```

What's the conceptual difference? Why should I use the taglib rather than HTML? Is there a preferred method within the world of Struts and the JSP community at large?

Comment: Thanks to everybody who provided answers and insight to this most basic of questions. I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Struts 2 tags serve two primary purposes:

1. Theming (e.g., "what's emitted")
2. Framework integration (e.g., values, validation)

Struts 2 uses "themes" to determine what is output for view-oriented tags. The default "xhtml" theme, for example, wraps the input tags in table rows, sets the input field value, displays field validation errors if any, and probably a few other things I'm not recalling.

If you look at the page source you can see precisely what the differences are, except for the bits that are determined by back-end functionality like the if/then around validation messages.

In general, custom tags allow you to abstract view-layer functionality in arbitrary ways. The "preferred method" is to not do stuff by hand, which is what you'd need to do in order to duplicate even the simplest functionality like setting the value from the action and displaying error messages.

You can *see* what the custom tags do by looking at their FreeMarker templates (assuming you're not using the Java tags). You can extend those templates, create your own templates, etc. all under the framework's purview.

Even a cursory examination of the S2 tag and theming docs should answer this question.

Comment: When it comes to writing your own app based on Struts, would the defacto method be using Strut taglib and then applying themes to it as appropriate?

Comment: @AndrewWeir ... Yes, you would normally use the S2 tags, particularly the UI ones. Turn the question on its head: why *wouldn't* you use existing framework functionality and instead roll your own or do it all by hand?

Comment: It could be language features above-and-beyond the need for some apps. JSP and Tomcat have been postured to the enterprise level, and the over complexity isn't required until you hit problems. Incidentally, the documentation is very haphazard, and not very clear when it comes to "how to do" something using Struts. I don't find browsing it very concise or helpful.

Comment: @AndrewWeir Interesting, because the tutorial shows the usage of the tags. You can always file a JIRA ticket against specific documentation issues, or file a CLA and edit the documentation yourself to help clear things up. I don't really find anything "over complex" about filling in a form field value or showing validation errors, I guess, but YMMV.

Comment: It's probably more my own discomfort - moving away from writing raw HTML to Struts, where you then have to write using the taglib.

Comment: @AndrewWeir Almost every Java-ish web framework has a collection of custom tags. Custom tags allow abstraction at the view layer, and abstraction is generally a Good Thing. The few times I used PHP I still used methods to wrap up repetitive HTML and boilerplate stuff like the form label, validation, etc. It just doesn't make any sense to do that kind of work by hand.

Comment: Honestly, if you are using JSP as your view layer and you need to modify the templates anyway, there isn't really any downside to just making JSP tag files for your form and various input types. It allows for really easy templating, though I would only go this route if you were going to make significant changes to the templates and/or you wanted your templates in JSP tag format.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access server data with *pure* `HTML`; the alternative to `TagLibraries` inside a `JSP` is ***not*** the `HTML`, but the old (and bad) `Scriptlet`s.

Everything *at the end* will be transformed to `HTML`, but you need an intermediate tier to allow you handle business data.

How can you read serverside values with `HTML` ?

***Long story short:***

once was the **`Servlet`**, with its `PrintWriter`s to output `HTML`:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

    String myServerSideValue = "StackOverflow";

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();        
    writer.println("<html>");
    writer.println("<head>");
    writer.println("<title>Wait, what... a Servlet in 2013?!</title>");
    writer.println("</head>");
    writer.println("<body>");
    writer.println("<span>Hello " + myServerSideValue + "</span>");
    writer.println("</body>");
    writer.println("</html>");
}
```

Clearly a nightmare, that led some smart guy to invent `JSP`s and `Scriptlet`s:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Wait, what... Scriptlets in 2013?!</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <span>Hello <%= myServerSideValue %> </span>
   </body>
</html>
```

Then `TagLib`s like `JSTL` came out:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>you <i>may</i> still needs JSTL with, for example, Spring MVC</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <span>Hello <c:out value="myServerSideValue" /> </span>
   </body>
</html>
```

And finally `WebWork / Struts` brought `OGNL` to us

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>you still needs JSTL with, for example, Spring MVC</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <span>Hello <s:property value="myServerSideValue" /> </span>
   </body>
</html>
```

Using `OGNL` inside `Struts2` tags is similar to `JSTL`, but **more powerful** and **fully integrated** in `Struts2` in several ways (`Validation`, `Theming`, etc).

Maybe this example is too nàive to understand why `Struts2 Tags` should be used instead `Scriptlets` or other `TagLibs`, but when coming to more complex, real-world scenarios, you will start to appreciate and maximize the usage of this great tool.

Comment: Scriptlets is still useful if you are working with jsp tags, they have not yet been canceled.

Comment: Yes, but the underlying question is: why using JSP tags (except for legacy app maintainment) ?

Comment: It's a rhetorical question, unless it's supported by the JSP spec. But if you want to drive on the mercedes then better use taglibs.

Comment: Struts tags are JSP tags, so I'm not sure I follow your comment, @AndreaLigios. JSTL and the JSP EL are less powerful than OGNL, but that isn't necessarily a bad thing. Besides, JSTL and JSP EL typically have much better tool support than OGNL.

Comment: @StevenBenitez, by JSP tags i mean standard tags, directives etc something beginning with `<%` or with `<jsp:`... your comment make me think that I've probably mis-read RomanC's comment from `Scriptlet is still useful EVEN if you are working with (custom) JSP tags` and not `Scriptlet is still useful if you are STILL working with (standard) tags`; and btw yes, they "can" be handy, about once time per year I use them too ;)

Comment: @AndreaLigios I'm not advocating scriptlets, just saying that JSP tags are really useful if you use JSP. JSP and JSP tags are definitely not legacy. :)

Comment: @StevenBenitez of course JSP are not legacy (I don't like FreeMarker nor Velocity very much, I'm not some Wicket evangelist or something, etc), I use them every day; and, if we consider Struts Tags as JSP Tags, then they're very useful. If instead we're talking about standard Tags, I disagree... In my latest projects there's almost no trace of them, so they're not that useful I guess, at least when using Struts2. I'm pretty sure we're saying the same thing, simply giving "wider/thinner" meanings to the "JSP tag" word, so... c'mon Tallahassee, I'm not hiding your Twinkies :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios LOL! Fair enough!